# Attribute Error: module 'provider' has no attribute 'getDataFiles'

Tags: python

I'm running a code and it gives me an error I can't solve !
how can I add the missing attribute?

the relevant part of the code :

```
ALL_FILES = provider.getDataFiles('indoor3d_sem_seg_hdf5_data/all_files.txt') #line 63
room_filelist = [line.rstrip() for line in open('indoor3d_sem_seg_hdf5_data/room_filelist.txt')]
```

The error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Research\Codes\pointnet\pointnet-master\sem_seg\train.py", line 63, in <module>
    ALL_FILES = provider.getDataFiles('indoor3d_sem_seg_hdf5_data/all_files.txt')
AttributeError: module 'provider' has no attribute 'getDataFiles'
```

Comment: Where is `provider` defined, do you do `import provider`, and then do its contents as shown by `dir(provider)` have the right contents like `getDataFiles`?

Comment: what is `provider`? Where did you get it from?

Comment: I do ```import provider``` and it's defined in another .py file and it does contain the definition of get files as follows ```def getDataFiles(list_filename):
    return [line.rstrip() for line in open(list_filename)]```

Answer (score 1):

First, check if you have `import provider` in your code, you can also do `from model import *`

I found out that you are using pointnet. So I search the source code and I found this method is:

```
def getDataFiles(list_filename):
    return [line.rstrip() for line in open(list_filename)]
```

You can search your library for this method. It might not be in the provider.py

You could just added this method to your code. But the best idea is to search for it.

For you case, the provider.py should be at `\pointnet\pointnet-master\`, and there is also a train.py at that location.

Comment: The function definition has `self` as the first attribute, so it is a member of a class.  It can't be called on its own like that.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that. Then, I would say just search for the right module.

Comment: you are right, it's pointnet, and the mentioned method didn't work.

Comment: Try         `from model import *`

Comment: I know that the provider.py file exists and it contains the definition you mentioned, that's why I'm confused and don't know what to do!

Comment: That's because the provider.py and your train.py is not under the same folder. When importing, you need to consider that.

Comment: @Zichzheng: this is hacking around PYTHONPATH. The directory containing `provider.py` needs to be on the PYTHONPATH. This is a duplicate of many existing questions.

Comment: @smci Yes, so I say just use `from model import *`. But for the pointnet, I think there are some modified version where the provider.py in another filename. If that case, he will need to search for the method and change the name.

Comment: @YoussefHany You will want to replace your `import provider` with `from model import *`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ! All I had to do is to copy the provider.py file into the sem.seg.py file which I used. It appears it couldn't find it in the previous file.